# Ubuntu redirect cron output to file

Tags: 16.04, cron

I'm trying to add a script file to the cronjob in order to execute it every minute and then print the output to a log file. But every time i open the log is empty

Here is my script (just a sample)

```
#!bin/sh
echo "hello"
```

And my cron tab

```
* * * * * /scripts/script.sh  >> var/log/file1.log (execute every minute)
```

and i already tried these commands from others stack overflow post

```
* * * * * /bin/sh ./scripts/script.sh >> var/log/file1.log 2>&1
* * * * * /scripts/script.sh > /dev/pts/2  #or at least try to put to console
* * * * *  /bin/sh ./scripts/script.sh 2> /dev/pts/2 #same as above
```

But something is missing.. any ideas? ...I'm new to linux

Comment: In `* * * * * /bin/sh ./scripts/script.sh >> var/log/file1.log 2>&1` its `/var/log/file1.log/` you were missing a "/" before "var". (Root is the parent directory of var)

Comment: Is it really *your* crontab - or root's? i.e. did you edit it with `sudo` or not? either way, don't use relative paths like `./scripts`- and when you use an absolute path `/scripts` make sure it's correct (is `scripts` really in the filesystem root directory `/`? or is it somewhere else like `/home/user/scripts`?)